# How to link scatter plots by a custom attribute with Bokeh python library?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have two scatter plots that use the box select tool, and are linked by x-value. I'm attempting to link the plots by an ID value. Is there a simple way of doing this with the existing Bokeh API?

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

N = 100
max = 100
x = np.random.random(size=N) * max
y1 = np.random.random(size=N) * max
y2 = np.random.random(size=N) * max
id = np.random.random(size=N) * max

output_file("scatter.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y1=y1, y2=y2))

TOOLS="box_select"

left = figure(width=400, height=400, tools=TOOLS, x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))
left.circle("x", "y1", source=source, size=10, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

right = figure(width=400, height=400, tools=TOOLS, x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))
right.circle("x", "y2", source=source, size=10, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two plots are not "linked by x-coordinate": it just looks that way because your points happen to have the same x-coordinate in both plots. If you assign two different x-coordinates (`x1` and `x2`) to each of the data points, you'll see that they're actually linked by their row number in the data table (you don't need to manually assign an `id`):

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_notebook, show, gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()
N = 100
max = 100
x1 = [0,10,20,30]
x2 = [50,20,10,70]
y1 = [10,10, 20, 20]
y2 = [30,0,30,0]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x1=x1, x2=x2, y1=y1, y2=y2))

TOOLS="box_select"

left = figure(width=400, height=400, tools=TOOLS, x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))
left.circle("x1", "y1", source=source, size=10, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

right = figure(width=400, height=400, tools=TOOLS, x_range=(0,100), y_range=(0,100))
right.circle("x2", "y2", source=source, size=10, fill_color="black", line_color=None)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])
show(p)
```